# How can you highlight a C compiler directive spanning multiple lines?

Tags: listings, color, highlighting

In my `\lstset{...}` I have `morecomment=[l][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{\#},` which I've seen used to give preprocessor commands colour. This works just fine but I'd like to get multi-line macros to be highlighted too, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
#define MAX(a, b) \
    ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
\end{lstlisting}
```

**What's a good way to get `listings` to match multi-line macros?**

[*EDIT*]
very well, here's a complete example with `\documentclass` etc... :P

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
    morecomment=[l][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{\#}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#define MAX(a, b) \
    ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the second line of the macro to be blue too, based on a rule relating to the `\`.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Side-question: can you actually do line continuation with a backslash in C? Not to my knowledge...

Comment: @Jubobs done. not in C exactly, but most compilers provide a [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) in which macros may escape newlines with a `\\`. It's just a readability thing afaik.

Comment: @Jubobs apologies for the delay. I wanted to give code a try first. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No bother. Glad I was able to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listings` package doesn't directly provide the means of highlighting a compiler directive that is continued over multiple lines. If you think that's a desirable feature, you might want to get in touch with the maintainer.

In the meantime, here is a possible implementation. It uses two switches with self-explanatory names to keep track of the context and patches `listings` in order to check, right before anything gets printed, whether we're still in a compiler directive; if so, the directive style is applied.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstloadaspects{directives}

% ---------- Beginning of ugly internals ----------
\makeatletter

% switches to keep track of context
\newif\if@LastCharWasBackslash
\newif\if@DirectiveContinued

% --- hooking into listings ---
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}%
{% 
  \ifx\lst@lastother\lstum@backslash%   % if the last character in
                                        % \the\lst@token is a backslash...
    \global\@LastCharWasBackslashtrue%
  \else
    \global\@LastCharWasBackslashfalse%
  \fi  
  \@condApplyDirectiveStyle             % Apply directive style if needed
}
\lst@AddToHook{Output}%
{%
  \global\@LastCharWasBackslashfalse%   % Reset switch
  \@condApplyDirectiveStyle%            % Apply directive style if needed 
}

% `listings' automatically exits CDmode at the EOL hook;
% we patch \lsthk@EOL so that it checks whether a compiler directive
% is continued on the next line and set the relevant switch accordingly.
\patchcmd{\lsthk@EOL}
  {\ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@CDmode \lst@LeaveMode \fi}
    {%
      \global\@DirectiveContinuedfalse%
      \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@CDmode%
        \lst@LeaveMode
    \else
        \if@LastCharWasBackslash%
          \global\@DirectiveContinuedtrue%
        \fi
      \fi
    }
    {}{\@latex@error{\string\lsthk@EOL\space patch failed!}{}}

% --- two helper macros ---
\newcommand\@condApplyDirectiveStyle
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@CDmode%
    \@applyDirectiveStyle%
  \fi
  \if@DirectiveContinued%
    \@applyDirectiveStyle%
  \fi  
}

\newcommand\@applyDirectiveStyle{\let\lst@thestyle\lst@directivestyle}

\makeatother

% ---------- End of ugly internals ----------

\lstset
{
  language       = C,
  directivestyle = \color{blue},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#define MAX(a, b) \   
  ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define \
  bar \
  baz
foo \ bar
baz
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a workaround...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
    morecomment=[l][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{\#},
    moredelim=[il][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{@},
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#define MAX(a, b) \
@   ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to colour arbitrary lines, but the `moredelim` option with `i` hides the `@` character in the macro and colours the rest of the line just like `morecomment`.