# Syntax highlighting broken on multiline macros of C code listing

Tags: color, listings

Using the `listings` and `color` packages, I can get syntax highlighting on a C code listing quite easily:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}  %% Allow color names
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{Gray},
  stringstyle=\color{Black},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  showstringspaces=false
}        

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=customasm]{sample.c}

\end{document}
```

But the syntax highlighting breaks after a multiline preprocessor directive like the one I've got here:

```c
/* comment with
 * multiple lines */

#define MACRO1 "single line here"
#define MACRO2 "multiple \
 lines"
#define MACRO3 "syntax highlighting broken from here on :("

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from `pdflatex`. Notice how the third `define` (and everything else after it) is not highlighted:

[image: broken_sample]

Note that the same doesn't happen with string literals spanning multiple lines outside macros:

[image: non broken sample]

Is there anyway to fix this without modifying the C code file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you highlight a C compiler directive spanning multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160396/how-can-you-highlight-a-c-compiler-directive-spanning-multiple-lines)

Comment: @siracusa I've seen that one, but it seems the highlighting works well for the asker there, it just doesn't highlight the whole macro. In my case though, nothing below the macro gets highlighted.

Comment: So the problem seems to be the string literal in your directive. As soon as one spans several lines, the rest of the code gets messed up. Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly fix this

Comment: @siracusa that's a good observation. I did a test based on that and added the info to the question.